# Knockout MVC foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, foreach

There is ViewModel.

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

My product (you don't actually need it but nts):

```
public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

}
```

I want, using Knockout, create list of products on my page.
Here is my code:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@using Task13MVC.Domain
@model Task13MVC.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/_MyViewStart.cshtml";
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<table>
<tbody>
@using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => Model.Products))
{
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="item">
        @using (items.If(m => m.ImageData != null))
        {

            <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px">
                <img width="75" height="75" data-bind="attr:{'src':'@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product",new{id="How put there id?"})'"/>
            </div>
        }
      <h3>@items.Html.Span(m => m.Name)</h3>
      @items.Html.Span(m => m.Description);
        <div class="item">
            @items.Html.Button("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Cart", new { });
        </div>
        <h4>@items.Html.Span(m => m.Price.ToString())</h4>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

upd My result:

[image]

1. Why it's not going foreach, only once.
2. Why there is no result (where items.Html.Span must be).
3. How i can put productId in image source link attribute.

Comment: And what is your produced html?

Comment: why don't you use simple foreach instead of expression

Comment: Same with me. Using Razor foreach iterates fine and displays the data, but the Knockout foreach shows a single null entry.

When writing the for each using native syntax `data-bind="foreach: products"` it works as expected.